# File cant be downloaded fully using downloadmanager

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I was trying to download a file(could be any file) into a browser using a direct link. I tried with this:

```
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    this.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    this.webView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bw6vr2LNxB3iUFJrTk5oZDljaTA&export=download");

    this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());

}

private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient implements DownloadListener {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String u) {
        v.loadUrl(u);
        v.setDownloadListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse(url));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download.png"); 
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "end", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

My link is a direct downloadable link which only works in browser so i was trying to download it using a webview. But the file is not fully downloaded. For example in the [link](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bw6vr2LNxB3iUFJrTk5oZDljaTA&export=download) my image's size is 31KB but 3/4KB is downloaded.
May be it only download the html page because when i open the downloaded image into a webview it shows a html page.
What is the problem i didn't understand ? How can i solve this issue ??

Comment: I have the same problem with download Manager. I have tried to download the song with Download Manager, but can not succeed. The same song is downloaded with Asynctask.  Please share some hint if you find any solution.